# Changing content of activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm writing an Android 5.1 application (running landscape on a 10" tablet) where math tasks should be displayed. Of course I could write an activity for every task but then I would end with 100 activities... Thus I think it is better to have only one activity and just replacing the content.

On the top I would like to display the task (math formula in Latex or text), then there is some space where the user can solve the task (with a stylus) and at the bottom he can enter the result (or 4 choices are given). When the user submits the task a next task should be displayed.

How could this be done with only one activity?

Comment: As part of submitting the task, update the widgets in the activity with the contents for the next task. Those contents could come from database entries, some JSON you retrieve from a Web service, etc.

Comment: [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)s.

Comment: Just update whatever view with the new data. And clear any other views to a blank state